# Highstock - How to handle large data sets

Tags: dataset, highcharts

I've got a highstock going where I query my database for data.  My dataset isn't big yet, but I forsee it growing to have hundreds of thousands of data points.  That's a lot of data!  There's no way I'm going to pass that back through a call back.

I figure there's got to be a way to handle this.  Perhaps you can pass arguments to the query function/.php?  I've looked at #plotOptions.series.dataGrouping, but that still requires an original full data set.

How do the big cats do it?  How do Yahoo & Googs store discrete stock ticker data for XX years?  After N time, do they take the historic data, approximate it, and reduce the resolution?  If someone could point me in the right direction, I'm sure it's already been covered before, but a few searches didn't turn anything up.

Thanks,

-CD

Comment: Check [this article](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/48-loading-millions-of-points-in-highcharts), how to handle huge number of points in Highstock:

Comment: Yahtzee!  Great reference.  This was my gut instinct, and similar to what Javier suggested.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it doesn't make sense to know the values from one year ago with minute-resolution. It depends on you application, but if the purpose is to provide finantial information, I think that it is OK to assume that fine resolution is only interesting on recent dates. The same consideration applies to logging performance counters (such as MRTG does), and many other things.

For instance, you can mantain:

- A "last week" serie, with 1-minute resolution.
- A "last trimester" serie, with hour-resoultion.
- A historic serie, with daily resolution.

All but the finest series should store not only the average, but also the minimum and maximum values observed in each period, as well as other statistics indictators that might be of interest.